# Running stored procedure async

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, task

I'm trying to call a stored procedure asynchronously, like this:

```
protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => Trigger());
}

private void Trigger()
{
    var q = Db.Query("UPDATE RefreshConfig SET RefreshRequested = 1 WHERE RefreshRequested = 0 AND RefreshRunning = 0").ToList();
    var p = Db.Query("EXEC sp_ProceedPrices").ToList();
}
```

I don't need any result, it just needs to run in the background, it should take 2-3 minutes.

I'm getting this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Execution Timeout Expired.
>   The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> Inner Exception: Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

I've added `Connnection Timeout=0` to my connection string

```
<add name="DB" 
     connectionString="Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***DB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=***;Password=***;Connection Timeout=0"  
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: The update statement runs fine, it fails on the EXEC

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: "Connection timeout" only applies to the time consumed in establishing a connection to the db server. Your error is an execution timeout - the connection was successful (probably pulled from the pool) and the execution of the statement takes longer than allowed. I think that is a asp.net setting.

Comment: It was indeed the SqlCommand timing out. @SMor. Thanks.